# Explicitly allow Doorkeeper scope in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, doorkeeper

In my current application I have two doorkeeper scopes, `user` and `admin`. In the [doorkeeper documentation](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Using-Scopes) for setting scopes in an API it shows

```
class Api::V1::ProductsController < Api::V1::ApiController
  before_action -> { doorkeeper_authorize! :public }, only: :index
  before_action only: [:create, :update, :destroy] do
    doorkeeper_authorize! :admin, :write
  end

  ...
end
```

I don't want to call doorkeeper in every controller, so in my ApplicationController I have

```
module API
  module V1
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
      before_action { doorkeeper_authorize! :user, :project }
      ...

    end
  end
end
```

but I don't want to give `:project` access to every controller. Is there a way for me to allow `user` in our application controller `before_action { doorkeeper_authorize! :user }` and on a per-controller basis allow `project`? ie:

```
module API
  module V1
    class SomeController < ApplicationController
      before_action only: [:index, :show] { doorkeeper_authorize! :project }

      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by doing the following in my `API::V1::ApplicationController`

```
module API
  module V1
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
      WHITELISTED_PROJECT_CONTROLLERS = %w( projects pre_task_plans
                                            job_hazard_analyses ).freeze

      before_action :authorize!

      def authorize!
        if project_scope?
          if !WHITELISTED_PROJECT_CONTROLLERS.include?(controller_name)
            return user_not_authorized
          end
        end
        doorkeeper_authorize! :user, :project
      end

      def project_scope?
        doorkeeper_token&.scopes&.any? { |s| s == 'project' }
      end

     ...

    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a conditional with `controller_name` - smith like this:

`before_action { doorkeeper_authorize! :project }, 
  if: -> { controller_name == 'some' }`

Check if maybe you should pass a param to lambda like:

`if: ->(instance) { instance.controller_name == 'some' }`

Answer (score 0):

maybe creating your own filter might be an option

```
before_action :doorkeeper_user_authorize!,  only: [:create, :update, :destroy]
protected 

def doorkeeper_user_authorize!
  doorkeeper_authorize!( :user )
end 

def doorkeeper_project_authorize!
  doorkeeper_authorize!( :user, :project )
end
```

then in controller where project should be allowed

```
skip_before_action :doorkeeper_user_authorize!
before_action :doorkeeper_project_authorize!
```